# MVC Model Binding: Using a name different from the QueryString for the Method Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

Given a URL:

> http://www.stackoverflow.com/question?**ask**=123&**answers**=5

and its corresponding ActionMethod and Model:

```
public ActionResult Question(RequestObject request)
{
   return View("Question", request);
}

public class RequestObject
{
   public string AskId
   {
      get;
      set;
   }

   public string NumberOfAnswers
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
}
```

Notice that the QueryString and the parameters of the RequestObject are different. Can I achieve that with the default binding behavior? Do I need to create a custom binder?

Thanks!

Comment: I am having same problem and I dont know why default model binder does not consider parameters from Query String.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a custom model binder is what you want. Scott Hanselman has a good example of implementing custom binders [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use explicit object initialization:

```
public ActionResult Question(string ask, string answers)
{
    return View("Question", new RequestObject
    {
        AskId = ask,
        NumberOfAnswers = answers
    });
}
```

Comment: That's what I have at this point, but I want to move to MVC Model Bindings as I have not just two arguments but several.

Answer (score 0):

Override DefaultModelBinder. Particularily, its `BindProperty` method.